# How to align data in list view? JavaFX

Tags: java, listview, javafx, fxml, text-align

I have problem with ListView. My application read and parse data from .csv file, then I convert data to array and show in ListView. I need align data like this:

[image: example of align data]

But my solution is this:

[image: unaligned data]

Can you help me?

Comment: The sample image with aligned data looks like a TableView (with skipped column headers and lines) to me. I am pretty sure you can not "align" the content inside a ListView into columns.

Comment: @ChristophGiesche Both screens show listview. Finally I know, how a professor did it. He only used String format and tabulators ("\t"). Only 2 - 3 colums are aligned, but nevermind but thanks for you idea, I appreciate it.

Comment: Please tell your Professor about TableView ;). I am getting goosebumps when I hear "String format and tabulators ("\t")" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like to use a list and not a table you could create a custom list cell. Here is a nice post [Custom ListCell](http://www.billmann.de/2013/07/03/javafx-custom-listcell/) with source code which you could easily transfer to your needs.

Comment: Thank you, it is what I want :)

Answer (score 1):

To align your data into columns, i would suggest to use a TableView. You can find an example here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm

You can change the look and feel of a TableView to match your needs.